OpenAPI Swagger Documentation Jargons
I have configured OpenAPI documentation in my spring boot application. Everything is coming that is expected but there are a lot of jargons coming up. Only the highlighted and ticked values are required to be there.


I tried using @Hidden annotation which resulted in hiding the actual endpoints leaving the unnecessary stuff. I tried @API as well.
This is the dependency for springdoc-openapi being used.
implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.1.0
and this is the config file.
package com.bma.directory.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.OpenAPI;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.info.Contact;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.info.Info;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.info.License;

@Configuration
public class StudentDirectorySwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public OpenAPI apiInfo() {
        return new OpenAPI().info(new Info().title("StudentDirectory_V1").description(readSwaggerDocument().toString())
                .version("v1").contact(new Contact().name("John deere").email("abcd@gmail.com")).license(new License().name("Student Directory Document")
                        .url("https://github.com")));
    }

    private StringBuilder readSwaggerDocument() {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append(
                "StudentDirectory_v1 api is a CRUD application that "
                + "posts and retrieves information about one or more student at a time"
                );
        return stringBuilder;
    }

}


package com.bma.directory.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.bma.directory.service.StudentDirectoryServiceImpl;
import com.bma.directory.vo.error.CommonErrorVO;
import com.bma.directory.vo.input.StudentDetailsRequestVO;
import com.bma.directory.vo.output.StudentDetailsResponseVO;

import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Operation;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Content;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.responses.ApiResponse;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.responses.ApiResponses;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "student/directory")
public class StudentDirectoryServiceController {

    @Autowired
    private StudentDirectoryServiceImpl studentDirectoryServiceImpl;

    @Operation(method = "POST", summary = "Gets the students details."
            + "Sample URL -http://{....}/bma/studentdirectory/abc", description = "Gets the student information")
    @ApiResponses(value = { @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "Successful", content = {
            @Content(mediaType = "applicayion/json", schema = @Schema(implementation = StudentDetailsResponseVO.class)) }),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "500", description = "Internal Server Error", content = {
                    @Content(mediaType = "applicayion/json", schema = @Schema(implementation = CommonErrorVO.class)) }),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "401", description = "Unauthorized", content = {
                    @Content(mediaType = "applicayion/json", schema = @Schema(implementation = CommonErrorVO.class)) }),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "403", description = "Forbidden", content = {
                    @Content(mediaType = "applicayion/json", schema = @Schema(implementation = CommonErrorVO.class)) }),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "404", description = "Not Found", content = {
                    @Content(mediaType = "applicayion/json", schema = @Schema(implementation = CommonErrorVO.class)) }),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "400", description = "Bad Request", content = {
                    @Content(mediaType = "applicayion/json", schema = @Schema(implementation = CommonErrorVO.class)) }), })
    @PostMapping(value = "/read/studentdetails")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<StudentDetailsResponseVO> getStudentDetails(
            @RequestBody StudentDetailsRequestVO studentDetailsInputVO) {
        StudentDetailsResponseVO studentDetailsOutputVO = studentDirectoryServiceImpl
                .getStudentDetails(studentDetailsInputVO);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(studentDetailsOutputVO, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}

